# Xcode debug issues with realm

Tags: xcode, swift, realm, lldb

I'm a little confused as to why `p self.session` and `po self.session` are returning different values?

Which one should I trust in my debugging?  It would appear my object is `nil` but then it would also appear it isn't.

[image]

[image]

Is my `session.messages` nil or is it set???

Answer (score 3):

Guess i  should have read the docs.

> Debugging
>
> Debugging apps using Realm’s Swift API must be done through the LLDB
>   console.
>
> Note that although the LLDB script installed via our Xcode Plugin
>   allows inspecting the contents of your Realm variables in Xcode’s UI,
>   this doesn’t yet work for Swift. Instead, those variables will show
>   incorrect data. You should instead use LLDB’s po command to inspect
>   the contents of data stored in a Realm.

Answer (score 3):

Just so the basics are clear:

1) The lldb `p` command (an alias for `expr --`) evaluates the expression following the "--", and then uses memory inspection and the "data formatters" mechanism in lldb (type summaries & synthetic children, see: http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html for more details) to print the values of a variable.

2) The lldb `po` command (an alias for `expr -O --`) evaluates the given expression, and then asks the resulting object whether is has a way of describing itself (a `description` or `debugDescription` method in ObjC or a Mirror in Swift) and if it does, prints the string returned by that object.  If it doesn't, it returns the result of #1.

Most likely, Realm was using some data formatters to present their objects via `p` for ObjC and those don't exist for yet for Swift.  But the object still knows how to present its debug description correctly, which is why `po` works.