# Realm Threading Confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, swift, realm

So I'm working on setting up a background queue that does all realm writes on its own thread.  I've run into some strange issues I can't figure out.

#### Issue #1

I'm not sure if this is related (see post: [Xcode debug issues with realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186075/xcode-debug-issues-with-realm)) but I do have an apparent mismatch with my `lldbg` output as to whether a certain field: 
`messages` element

## My DataTypes

#### OTTOSession

```
class OTTOSession : Object {
  dynamic var messages : MessageList?
  dynamic var recordingStart  : Double = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

func addLocationMessage(msg : dmParsedMessage) -> LocationMessage {
    let dmsg : dmLocationMessage = msg as! dmLocationMessage
    let locMsg = LocationMessage(locMsg: dmsg)
    self.messages!.locationMessages.append(locMsg)
    return locMsg;
  }
}
```

#### MessageList

```
public class MessageList : Object     {

dynamic var date : NSDate = NSDate();
dynamic var test : String = "HI";
let locationMessages = List<LocationMessage>()
let ahrsMessages = List<AHRSMessage>()
//    let statusMessages = List<StatusMessageRLM>()
let logMessages = List<LogMessage>()
}
```

## Realm Interactions

In my code I create my new `OTTOSession` in a code block on my `realmQueue`

```
internal var realmQueue = dispatch_queue_create("DataRecorder.realmQueue", 
                                                   DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

All realm calls are done on this `realmQueue` thread

```
  dispatch_async(realmQueue) {
        self.session = OTTOSession()
    }
```

I've also tried different variants such as:

```
  dispatch_async(realmQueue) {
        self.session = OTTOSession()

        // Directly making a message list
        self.session!.messages = MessageList()

        //Making a separate message list var
        self.messages = MessageList()
        self.session!.messages = self.messages
    }
```

*The reason I've played around with the `MessageList` is that I cant tell from the debugger whether the `.messages` variable is set or not*

#### Recording

Once I signal to my processes I want to start recording I then actually make the write calls into Realm (which I'm not 100% sure i'm doing correctly)

```
dispatch_async(realmQueue){

        // Update some of the data
        self.session!.recordingStart = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

        // Then start writing the objects
        try! Realm().write {

            // I've tried different variants of:
            let session = self.session!
            try! Realm().add(self.session!)                          
            // Or
            try! Realm().add(self.session!)

            // or            
            let session = self.session!                
            session.messages = MessageList()
            session.messages!.ahrsMessages
            try! Realm().add(self.session!)
            try! self.session!.messages = Realm().create(MessageList)
            try! Realm().add(self.session!.messages!)

            print ("Done")
        }
    }
```

Basically I've tried various combinations of trying to get the objects into realm.

**Question:  When adding an object with a `one-to-one` relationship do I have to add both objects to Realm or will just adding the `parent` object cause the related object to also be added to realm**

#### Adding Data

Where things start to go awry is when I start adding data to my objects.

Inside my `OTTOSession` Object I have the following function:

```
func addLocationMessage(msg : dmParsedMessage) -> LocationMessage {
    let dmsg : dmLocationMessage = msg as! dmLocationMessage
    let locMsg = LocationMessage(locMsg: dmsg)

    // THIS LINE IS CAUSING A 'REALM ACCESSED FROM INCORRECT THREAD ERROR
    self.messages!.locationMessages.append(locMsg)

    return locMsg;
}
```

I'm getting my access error on this line:

> self.messages!.locationMessages.append(locMsg)

Now the function call itself is wrapped in the following block:

```
dispatch_async(realmQueue) {
    try! Realm().write {
        self.session?.addLocationMessage(msg)
   }
}
```

So as far as I can tell by looking at the debugger - and by looking at the code - everything should be running inside the right thread.

My queue is `SERIAL` so things should be happening one after another.  The only thing I can't figure out is when I break at this point the debugger does show that `messages` is `nil` but I cant trust that because:

[image]

## Question

So my question is two fold

1) Is my code for adding an object into the RealmDB correct.  i.e. do I need to make two separate `Realm().add` calls for both the `OTTOSession` and the `MessageList` or can I get away with a single call

2) Is there anything that pops out to explain why I'm getting a thread violation here - should doing all my realm writing calls on a single thread be enough ?

Comment: It would be better, if you could separate concerns next time and address them individually by separated questions. That makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Addressing your troubles with LLDB: do you have the Realm plugin installed meanwhile? With that the output on both panes should be in sync. When in doubt, you can trust the dynamically evaluated result of `po` as that has always full knowledge over Realm's internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, you don't need to make two separate calls to `Realm.add()`. When you add an object to a Realm all related objects are persisted as well.

2) Your thread violation very likely originates from the fact that dispatch queues make no guarantee over the thread on which they are executed on (beside the main queue). So that means your Realm queue is executed on different threads. You will need to make sure to retrieve your session object from a Realm opened on this thread. You might want to use primary keys for that purpose and share those between queues / threads.